# How to split a single polygon with another polygon (from a different layer) with Qgis

Tags: qgis, polygon, mapinfo, splitting

I have two polygon layers: Zones and Neighbourhoods. I need to manually split one polygon of my Zones layer into two polygons, and the resulting two polygons need to be related to the neighbourhoods.

In the images below, Zones are pink outlined; Neighbourhoods are blue areas. First image is what I have now, second image is what I would like to have (two polygons splitted by the blue line)

[image]
[image]

I used to do this operation in Mapinfo, following these steps:

1. making Zones layer editable,
2. selecting the polygon of the Zones layer to be cut,
3. then Objects > Set Target,
4. then select the polygon of the Neighbourhoods layer that serves as the clipper,
5. Object > Split,
6. Clear Target.

Can I do something simmilar in Qgis (I am using version 2.18.11)?

Comment: check out the answers here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160240/cut-clip-split-a-polygon-with-another-polygon-from-same-layer