# How to create and modify a multipolygon so that it does not overlap when merging layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, tableau

I am new to QGIS. I need to modify a shapefile so I can add a circle in a Canadian province to be used for Tableau afterwards.

I tried to use QGIS to modify the shapefile. I have created a new layer and I have merged it with the one containing the Canadian province boundaries. The result is as shown in the screencap below. 
Instead of this result, I would like the circle to act as a province in itself so I don't have the overlapping of the province and the circle. Can this be achieved when merging 2 layers?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160240/cut-clip-split-a-polygon-with-another-polygon-from-same-layer and see if your problem is similar to the question being asked, if so you might find the answers helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a basic Union operation would suffice. Instead of working against topology, you should work with it.