# Seeking QGIS 3.4 equivalent of MapInfo Erase Target tool?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, mapinfo, erase

Is there a QGIS 3.4 equivalent of MapInfo's Erase target?

I'm editing a habitat map from aerial imagery, and adding in a lot of new features. I was doing this on MapInfo, so I was drawing a new polygon (e.g. around a pond), setting the target to the overlapping polygon (e.g. the field that the pond is in) and erasing the target by the selected feature (the pond I just drew). The tool is explained [here](http://webhelp.infovista.com/Planet/62/Subsystems/MapInfo/Content/pro_help/mapbuffer/erasingobjects.html)

I now have had to swap to QGIS, so wondering if anyone can tell me which tool/plugin I can use to replicate this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get, what "Erase Target" does. Does it deleted the whole polygon, or does it create a hole/ring, or what?

Comment: You set a target polygon, and then you select the polygon you want to use as a mask. Erase Target then removes the area of the target polygon for the selected mask polygon if that makes sense? See here: http://webhelp.infovista.com/Planet/62/Subsystems/MapInfo/Content/pro_help/mapbuffer/erasingobjects.html

Comment: please use the [edit] link to make changes to your question

Comment: I've added the link to the question - is that what you meant Ian?

Comment: Are both polygons on different or the same layer?

Comment: They're both part of the same layer

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility without using plugins: Add the `advanced digitizing toolbar` to your GUI (see below), then set the layer to editing mode and use the `add ring` tool (fifth from the left) to punch a hole in the larger polygon.

[image]

Though not as comfortable as the plugin, with enabled tracing/snapping you can create the hole with four additional clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question!

You need to use the [Clipper](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/clipper/) plug-in as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160240/cut-clip-split-a-polygon-with-another-polygon-from-same-layer)

Select the polygon you want to erase by and use the clipper tool. This then erased a hole in the overlapping polygon as per the polygon I selected.