# How to divide polygon into multiple zones given several points (Network Paritition)

Tags: qgis, network

I'm new to QGIS. I have a layer containing all the points of interest. I will like to divide a city into different zones (service area) depending on the location of these points so that each zone will be served by each point. How do I go about doing this in QGIS?

Example: https://www.caliper.com/glossary/what-is-network-partitioning.htm

Answer (score 2):

One method might be to [create Voronoi polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/voronoipolygons.html) around your points.  Then [Clip the resulting Voronoi polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160240/cut-clip-split-a-polygon-with-another-polygon-from-same-layer) to the shape of your city boundary.

Of course, these 'zones' would only be the areas in your city closest to the original points and would in no way consider population densities, driving routes, drive times, or other geographical features that question the usefulness of the Voronoi.